# Combining duplicate assoc array values into an appended key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like so (abstracted for clarity):

```
$foo = array(
   'breakfast' => 'a daily meal',
   'lunch' => 'a daily meal',
   'dessert' => 'a special treat',
   'snack' => 'a special treat',
   'plates' => 'tableware'
);
```

for which I would like to combine all the keys of duplicate values into a single "merged" key - so that `print_r($foo);` would be like so:

```
Array
(
[breakfast|lunch] => 'a daily meal'
[dessert|snack] => 'a special treat'
[plates] => 'tableware'
)
```

Currently I'm accomplishing this through a long nested series of ugly foreach statements... is there an easier/more appropriate way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're "grouping" on the values, I built a temporary array `$result` that mapped values in `$foo` to any matching keys in `$foo`. With that, it was simple to identify duplicates by their values and concatenate their keys. An [`array_flip`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) at the end will return just what you're looking for.

```
function merge_values(array $arr) {
    $result = array();

    foreach ( $arr as $key => $val ) {
        if ( isset($result[$val]) )
            $result[$val] .= '|' . $key;
        else
            $result[$val] = $key;
    }

    return array_flip($result);
}
```

See the result: http://ideone.com/iTUFY

```
array(3) {
  ["breakfast|lunch"]=>
  string(12) "a daily meal"
  ["dessert|snack"]=>
  string(15) "a special treat"
  ["plates"]=>
  string(9) "tableware"
}
```

Comment: All of these solutions are better than what I was doing, but the key was `array_flip` - I missed this function and this was essentially what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think so. Starting with your $foo we add...

```
$collector = array();
$newFoo = array();
foreach ($foo as $key=>$value){
    if (isset($collector[$value])){
        $collector[$value] .= '|'.$key;
    } else {
        $collector[$value] = $key;
    }
}

foreach ($collector as $keyValue=>$itemIndex){
    $newFoo[$itemIndex] = $keyValue;
}
```

There's not much elegance to my answer but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, may be:

```
$foo = array(
   'breakfast' => 'a daily meal',
   'lunch' => 'a daily meal',
   'dessert' => 'a special treat',
   'snack' => 'a special treat',
   'plates' => 'tableware'
);
$new = array();
foreach($foo as $key => $value){
    $keyNew = array_search($value,$new);
    if ($keyNew){
        unset($new[$keyNew]);
        $new[$keyNew . "|" . $key] = $value;
    }else
        $new[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($new);
```